# English names for Machi Koro cards

Tags: reference, machi-koro

My version of Machi Koro is not in English and none of the online manuals I found contain the building names.

Can anyone provide a complete list of card cost and names? Card text would be helpful as well.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

English language translations for the base game as well as two expansions are available at BoardGameGeek. [Here](https://boardgamegeek.com/filepage/104225/machi-koro-english-card-paste-ups-base-game-2-expa) is a link.

```
Value  Name
 1     Wheat Field  
 2     Livestock Farm  
 2-3   Bakery  
 3     Café  
 4     Convenience Store  
 5     Forest  
 6     Stadium  
 6     TV Station  
 6     Business Complex  
 7     Cheese Factory  
 8     Furniture Factory  
 9     Mine  
 9-10  Restaurant  
10     Apple Orchard  
11-12  Produce Market
```

And these are the landmarks:

```
Cost   Name
 4     Train station   
10     Shopping Mall  
16     Amusement Park  
22     Radio Tower
```